# SoapFault Exception: Lack of synchronization between sender and receiver clocks

Tags: php, api, soap, linux-kernel

I am using a DocuSign API and have run into some issues.
When sending the data request to their server I am getting the following error:

```
SoapFault exception: [q0:InvalidSecurity] An error was discovered 
processing the <Security> header ---> WSE065: Creation time of the 
timestamp is in the future. This typically indicates lack of synchronization 
between sender and receiver clocks. Make sure the clocks are synchronized 
or use the timeToleranceInSeconds element in the microsoft.web.services3 
configuration section to adjust tolerance for lack of clock synchronization.
```

I have looked all over their community forums and the only response I can find from their forum admin is this:

```
The message means that the client clock is wrong. The timezone might be set 
incorrectly. If the SOAP request is timestamped too far in the future or in the 
past, the server will reject it.  We generally run into this error with mobile 
apps since folks don't always have their devices set to sync to network time.
```

I checked my server time as well as my computer time to make sure everything is fine. My computer time is set to EST, and the server is set to CST. I have tried updated and synchronized my system clock on my computer as well as trying to adjust my timezone to CST to make sure they both match. I have also changed my computer time to GMT because that is what they say their server time is. I have also tried updating my server's clock since it seems to be the one that is a little bit off. (there seems to be like a 6 minute difference between my clock and the server clock).

**I ran this command on the server:**

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

**Response:**

```
27 Sep 08:51:41 ntpdate[18858]: step time server 91.189.94.4 offset -357.639332 sec
```

I also tried editing my grub configuration file on the server (/boot/grub/grub.conf). **I tried adding different combinations of these params to the end of the kernel line:**

```
clock=pit 
acpi=off 
noapic
```

**As well as trying to update the hardware clock with this command:**

```
hwclock=systohc
```

**The soap headers are as follows:**

This request was sent out at 10:41AM(my computer time [EST]), 9:47AM (my server time [CST]).

**Request:**

```
POST /api/3.0/api.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.docusign.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.3.16
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/CreateEnvelope"
Content-Length: 116157
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 1696
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 27 Sep 2012 14:41:13 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=7776000; includeSubDomains
```

If anyone has any thoughts as to what might be causing this error, or if anyone has any further advice on how to go about synchronizing my clocks, I would love to hear them.

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: First of all you need to debug that. Which request headers are send with the SOAP request? http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequestheaders.php

Comment: I took a look at my headers and I'm still not sure where to go from here. I have added them to my post.

Comment: Is there a timestamp in the soap request body probably? I don't see anything in the request headers that is telling a time, so probably it is in the body?

Comment: nope, unfortunately there is no timestamp in the body either.

Comment: Than this seems to be unrelated to the soap client. You need to create a network dump of the request and analyze that one for the time value being transmitted. Otherwise a problem might be that you are not sending the time value *at all* and this is why the exception happens. Check the documentation if you are required to send soap-headers and which values they need to contain.

Comment: I checked the documentation and it looks as though the timestamp is encoded with the document information when it is sent off in the body of the headers. That's why I couldn't find it when looking through the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up contacting the company I am hosting my virtual server with and as it turns out it wasn't an issue with anything I have control over at all. It turned out that their hypervisor (virtual machine monitor - VMM) was having issues so when my server was synchronizing its time from it, my time was getting offset by about 7 minutes. Since the system clock of my server was being controlled by it, this also disallowed me from being able to set the time manually with this command:

```
date -s "27 SEP 2012 HH:MM:SS"
```

since the changes would just be superseded by the VMM.